# Will the Database connection be closed if we yield the datareader row and not read all the records?

Tags: c#, database, .net, resources

While understanding how `yield` keyword works, I came across [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147045/return-datareader-from-method) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252531/returning-a-sqldatareader) on StackOverflow which advocates the use of `yield return` while iterating over the DataReader and it suits my need as well. But It makes me wonder as what happens, if I use `yield return` as shown below and if I don't iterate through entire DataReader, will the DB connection stay open forever?

```
IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetRecords()
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"...");
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(@"...", myConnection);
    myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    myConnection.Open();
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    try
       {               
          while (myReader.Read())
          {
            yield return myReader;          
          }
        }
    finally
        {
            myReader.Close();
        }
}


void AnotherMethod()
{
    foreach(var rec in GetRecords())
    {
       i++;
       System.Console.WriteLine(rec.GetString(1));
       if (i == 5)
         break;
  }
}
```

I tried the same example in a sample Console App and noticed while debugging that the finally block of `GetRecords()` is not executed. How can I ensure then the closure of DB Connection? Is there a better way than using `yield` keyword? I am trying to design a custom class which will be responsible for executing select SQLs and stored procedures on DB and will return the result. But I don't want to return the DataReader to the caller. Also I want to make sure that the connection will be closed in all scenarios.

**Edit** Changed the answer to Ben's answer as it is incorrect to expect method callers to use the method correctly and with respect to DB connection it will be more expensive if the method is called multiple times for no reason.

Thanks Jakob and Ben for detailed explanation.

Comment: From  what I see you are not opening the connection in the first place

Comment: @Frisbee Edited :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you will face the problem you describe: until you finish iterating over the result, you will keep the connection open. There's two general approaches I can think of to deal with this:

### Push, don't pull

Currently you're returning an `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>`, a data structure you can pull from. Instead, you could switch your method to *push* its results out. The simplest way would be to pass in an `Action<IDataRecord>` which is called on each iteration:

```
void GetRecords(Action<IDataRecord> callback)
{
    // ...
      while (myReader.Read())
      {
        callback(myReader);
      }
}
```

Note that given you're dealing with a collection of items, `IObservable`/`IObserver` might be a slightly more appropriate data structure, but unless you need it, a simple `Action` is much more straightforward.

### Eagerly Evaluate

An alternative is just to make sure the iteration entirely completes before returning.

You can normally do this by just putting the results in a list then returning that, but in this case there's the additional complication of each item being the same reference to the reader. So you need something to extract the result you need from the reader:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetRecords<T>(Func<IDataRecord,T> extractor)
{
    // ...
     var result = new List<T>();
     try
     {
       while (myReader.Read())
       {
         result.Add(extractor(myReader));         
       }
     }
     finally
     {
         myReader.Close();
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: I am using the approach you named Eagerly Evaluate. Now will it be a memory overhead if my SQLCommand's Datareader returns multiple outputs (like myReader.NextResult()) and I construct a list of list? Or sending the datareader to the caller [I personally don't prefer it] will be much efficient? [but the connection will be open longer]. What I am precisely confused here is between the tradeoff of keeping the connection open longer than creating a list of list. You can safely assume that there will be close to 500+ people visiting my webpage which connects to DB.

Comment: @GawdePrasad It depends what the caller would do with the reader. If it would just put items in a collection itself, there's no significant overhead. If it'd do an operation that doesn't require keeping the whole lot of values in memory, then there's a memory overhead. However unless you're storing very large amounts, it's probably not an overhead you should care about. Either way, there shouldn't be a significant time overhead.

Comment: How does the "push, don't pull" approach solves the "until you finish iterating over the result, you will keep the connection open" issue? The connection is still kept open until you finish iterating even with this approach, isn't it?

Comment: @BornToCode See the question: "if I use yield return as shown below and if I don't iterate through entire DataReader, will the DB connection stay open forever". The problem is that you return an IEnumerable and every caller who handles it has to be aware of this special gotcha: "If you don't finish iterating over me, I'll hold open a connection". In the push method, you take that responsibility away from the caller- they have no option to partially iterate. By the time control is returned to them, the connection is closed.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I like the push approach, because if you have a big query that you are presenting in a paged fashion, you can abort the read earlier for speed by passing in a Func<> rather than an Action<>; this feels cleaner than making the GetRecords function also do paging.

Answer (score 10):

Your `finally` block will always execute.

When you use `yield return` the compiler will create a new nested class to implement a state machine.

This class will contain all code from `finally` blocks as separate methods. It will keep track of the `finally` blocks that need to be executed depending on the state. All necessary `finally` blocks will be executed in `Dispose` method.

According to C# language specification, `foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement` is expanded to

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded - statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        … // Dispose e
    }
}
```

so the enumerator will be disposed even if you exit the loop with `break` or `return`.

To get more information about iterator implementation you can read this [this article by Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx)

**Edit**

The problem with such approach is that you rely on the clients of your class to use the method correctly. They could for example get the enumerator directly  and iterate through it in a `while` loop without disposing it.

You should consider one of the solutions suggested by @BenAaronson.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. I had put the breakpoint after the while loop so it was not breaking there. But now after putting the breakpoint in finally block [yes Silly me], I understand it better. The finally block is called as soon as the Foreach loop breaks and before the

Comment: This is extremely unreliable. For example: `var records = GetRecords(); var first = records.First(); var count = records.Count()` will actually execute that method twice, opening and closing the connection and reader each time. Iterating over it twice does the same thing. You might also pass the result around for a long time before actually iterating over it, etc. Nothing in the method signature implies that kind of behaviour

Comment: @BenAaronson I focused on the specific question about the current implementation in my answer. If you look at the whole problem, I agree it's much better to use the way you suggested in your answer.

Comment: @JakubLortz Fair enough

Comment: @BenAaronson The example you provided is just horrible client code. Consumers of IEnumerable is supposed to expect that they might come from an expensive source.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen The 'Get' part in the method name suggests that calling it actually retrieves data. And you can't assume that clients will always use the API in a correct way. If they can use it incorrectly, they will.

Comment: @JakubLortz by that logic we should just remove IEnumerable from the BCL, but it has proven useful enough to base Linq on top of it.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen Usually when you try to make something idiot-proof, you lose some functionality. You need to balance it out. Here we don't lose much by eagerly loading the results. Anyway, the biggest problem for me is the naming. When I see a method named `GetRecords` returning `IEnumerable`, I expect it to load the records to memory. On the other hand, if it was a property `Records`, I would rather assume it's some kind of abstraction over database.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen Well, see my comments on nvoigt's answer. I have no problem in general with methods returning an IEnumerable that will do significant work when iterated over, but in this case it doesn't seem to fit the implications of the method signature

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of the specific `yield` behaviour, your code contains execution paths that will not dispose your resources correctly. What if your second line throws an exception or your third? Or even your fourth? You will need a very complex try/finally chain, or you can use `using` blocks.

```
IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetRecords()
{
    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(@"..."))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using(var command = new SqlCommand(@"...", connection);
        {
            using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
               while(reader.Read())
               {
                   // your code here.
                   yield return reader;
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

People have remarked that this is not intuitive, that people calling your method may not know that enumerating the result twice will call the method twice. Well, tough luck. That's the way the language works. That's the signal that `IEnumerable<T>` sends. There is a reason this does not return `List<T>` or `T[]`. People that do not know this need to be educated, not worked around.

Visual Studio has a feature called static code analysis. You can use it to find out if you have disposed resources properly.

Comment: The language allows iterating over `IEnumerable` to do all sorts of things, such as throwing totally unrelated exceptions or writing 5GB files to disk. Just because the language allows it doesn't mean that it's acceptible to return an `IEnumerable` that does it from a method which gives no indication that that will happen.

Comment: Returning an `IEnumerable<T>` **is** the indication that enumerating it twice will result in two calls. You will even get helpful warnings in your tools if you enumerate an enumerable multiple times. The point about throwing exceptions is equally valid regardless of return type. If that method would return a `List<T>` it would throw the same exceptions.

Comment: I do understand your point and to some extent I agree- if you're consuming a method that gives you an `IEnumerable` then caveat emptor. But I also think that as a method writer, you have a responsibility to adhere to what your signature implies. The method is called `GetRecords`, so when it returns you'd expect it to have, y'know, *gotten the records*. If it was called `GiveMeSomethingICanPullRecordsFrom` (or, more realistically `GetRecordSource` or similar) then a lazy `IEnumerable` would be more acceptable.

Comment: @BenAaronson I agree that for example in `File`, `ReadLines` and `ReadAllLines` can be easily told apart and that's a good thing. (Although it's more because of the fact that a method overload cannot differ by return type only). Maybe ReadRecords and ReadAllRecords would fit here as naming scheme as well.

Answer (score 2):

What you did seems wrong, but will work fine.

You should use an **IEnumerator<>**, as it also inherits **IDisposable**.

But because you are using a foreach, the compiler is still using an **IDisposable** to generate an **IEnumerator<>** for the foreach.

in facts, the foreach involves a lot of thing internaly.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459447/do-i-need-to-consider-disposing-of-any-ienumerablet-i-use